# Bot Deletes Triggered Events from Server Log (Discord)

Tags: discord, discord.py

I recently made a server clock bot that tells the time based on a set timezone. Now the problem is that because the bot makes 3 actions per minute (creates a channel, changes permission to lock/unlock that channel, and deletes that channel), our server monitor person gets infested with these 3 messages every minute. Is there a way for this bot to find its own entries and remove them from the list? Or would this just cause it to make 4 entries but 3 get deleted? The log is being monitored via ProBot if that helps any and support at ProBot has said it is not possible on their end (interface level).

Answer (score 0):

The discord audit log is something nobody can change, it's intended like that. Nobody can take any administrative action without it being logged so theres always a papertrail. The only partial solution is the filtering option in the audit log, you can't exclude users/categories but at least you can select a single user/category and look at their/the categories actions without clutter.

What you could do is make your bot do its own audit logging in a channel, where it logs everything the audit log would log aside from your make-change-delete events

Comment: Will this add more clutter. I just "resolved" this by making a second channel and having the 3 change logs that the clock makes sent there. This way they can mute the channel "clock log" and keep notifications on for "server log".